# iPhone 4 with BLE using core Blue tooth 4.0

Tags: iphone, core-bluetooth, mfi

i have iPhone 4 not 4S and later , and I want to communicate my App with Blue Tooth low energy devices with MFI Compliant.

Is there any Solution..??? My device is not jailbroken.

Akhzar Nazir

Comment: If the device lacks Bluetooth Low Energy hardware then you can not communicate with it over Bluetooth Low Energy.

Answer (score 3):

The only option available for Bluetooth accessories on an iPhone 4 is an MFI certified accessory or a generic accessory such as a headset or keyboard.  The iPhone 4 does not have a Bluetooth 4/Bluetooth Low Energy chipset and so is not compatible with BLE devices. iPhone 4S and later support BLE.

Bluetooth Low Energy accessory devices are not covered by the MFI program.